# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate

Tags: android, exception, network-programming

My Android application was working perfectly but when my boss took it for a test he came accross an error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
```

What can be the reason for this error? And is there any way to handle this?

Comment: @RafaelOltra No. It's not a validation exception. They look different. As the message says, the peer hasn't sent a certificate at all.

Answer (score 3):

I had [this problem on my OUYA](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ouya-imagestore.htm#sni) as well. It basically means that the SSL certificate sent by the server is not deemed to be valid by the application/device.

Possible reasons:

- Current date not within valid-from and valid-to dates
- Signing certificate authority is not known/trusted
- Certificate is not for the hostname that has been requested (e.g. application requests `http://example.org/` but gets certificate for `http://othersite.example.org/`). If a desktop browser works with that site, the application may not support [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

Answer (score 1):

The peer hasn't sent an SSL certificate. This will be either because it doesn't own one that conforms to the constraints sent by this side, most probably that none of this side's trusted signers signed its certificate: or maybe it doesn't have one at all.